# Debug node.js backend application with an IDE, e.g. WebStorm

Tags: node.js, debugging, npm, webstorm

I added in package.json this into scripts:

```
"debug": "NODE_PATH=src nodemon --exec babel-node src/run.js --inspect",
```

It is pretending that it is debugging but jumping on selected lines how it pleases. I'm not that "expert" in JavaScript (I'm Java) but really this is pain in ass.

How can I debug backend without debug? Srry I'm angry because this is second time I'm giving change to JavaScript and this is second time I'm furious about this stupidity.

Thanks for any hints.

P.S.: if there is better software, tool to debug please just refer to it

Answer (score 0):

Right now, VSCode(Visual Studio Code) is considered as best tool for development, which is light weight and user friendly. 
You can get different extensions based on your requirement.

To debug node js in vscode, go to debug window -> add configuration -> type attach process -> press ctrl + space -> press enter on attach suggestion.

After that, run command, node "your file name" --inspect

Press F5, your debugger will  be attached

[Node js debugging using VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging)

Comment: I followed your steps. When i tried to add configuration i get this: "Cannot read property 'openConfigFile' of undefined" so after short browsing i added some launch.json which is something like this: 
"version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach by Process ID",
            "processId": "${command:PickProcess}"
        }
    ]

But when i run this command i get import error
node src/run.js --inspect
import http from 'http';

Comment: launch.json code
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach",
            "port": 9229
        }
    ]
}

Comment: Cannot connect to runtime process, timeout after 10000 ms - (reason: Cannot connect to the target: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9229).

Comment: port 9229 is free

Comment: For e.g. if you have a file named test.js, then you need to run it as, node --inspect test.js after running it press F5

Comment: I'm unable to run any of files like "node --inspect xxx.js" because i'm getting this kind of errors: "import http from 'http';"... this backend project will start rest server and catch http request and send responses. So i just wanna debug this requests. But when im trying to run it like node ..... is not working... when i try to run it from npm run dev or npm run debug it will start

Comment: Is dependencies installed in your project?

Answer (score 0):

In WebStorm, the easiest way to debug the application started via NPM stript is using the icon in the gutter: open your `package.json` in editor, right-click the icon to the left of your script and choose **debug**:

[image]

See also https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2017/09/debugging-node-js-apps-in-webstorm/

Note that:

- `babel-node` is deprecated and not recommended for using in production. To get ES6 code compiled on-the-fly, try running node with `-r @babel/register`. see https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-register
- by running `nodemon --exec babel-node src/run.js --inspect`, you pass `--inspect` to your application, not to node interpreter, so this command doesn't start the debugger. Node options have to be specified *before* the javascript file, otherwise the passed options will be treated as application arguments, not as node.js args

Comment: I tried the first one. Working same as from description. So i changed the config to this one: https://ibb.co/1KK7799 AND in scripts to this "debug": "NODE_PATH=src nodemon --exec babel-node src/run.js" but now no breakpoints are working.

Comment: try using `node -r @babel/register` instead of `babel-node`